# DX Shader Assembly Registers

Tags: directx, shader, pixel-shader

I'm starting to learn dx assembly but I'm really confused there are some registers i can't seem to find what are they for anywhere these registers are:

**mov_pp**

**mov_sat**

and basically all of them that have something different from normal assembly registers...
is there a tutorial anywhere for this?.

Basically what does "pp" and "sat" stand for?

Thanks

Comment: assembly shader language was obsolete since DirectX10, you should learn HLSL I think.

Comment: Thanks that's some really nice info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't registers. They are the `mov` instruction, which moves data between registers, with added instruction modifiers, described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219850%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The `_pp` modifier allows the instruction to run in partial precision.

The `_sat` modifier clamps the result to the range [0,1].